# How to run multiple, disjoint AJAX-generated Javascripts in a TIMELY manner?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Before you mark it as duplicate, please read in detail because it is NOT a duplicate.

I have this application were the AJAX call generates multiple HTML sections(wrapper divs) and associated JS for each section(wrapped div). Thanks to an earlier question asked here, I managed to have different sections of the HTML sections populate appropriate target Divs once the response comes from the AJAX call using Jquery filter() or find() methods. But that takes care of the HTML part. How about the associated JS? That is really not as simple as some suggestions have been given in different posts on this site. Here's why:

The server generated HTML/JS looks like this:

```
 <div id='div1'>
   server generated HTML markup here... A lot here...
    ...
 </div>
 <script> ... server generated Javascript here applicable to div1 </script>

 <div id='div2'>
   server generated HTML markup here... A lot here...
   ...
 </div>
 <script> ... server generated Javascript here applicable to div2 </script>
```

To populate different divs, I used JQuery "find" to extract the tags but "find" and filter() both strip the script tags.  One work around which I read about is to dump the entire response into a dummy hidden div and then process it from there. The problem with that is that the JS gets prematurely executed as soon as the AJAX response populates this dummy div and before the HTML sections are moved to their appropriate div targets.

So, I thought of a simple trick. Instead of generating script tags on the server, I generate some dummy tags on the server like

```
  <section1_script>....JS.... </section_script>
```

instead of the usual script tags as shown above. The JS now becomes some inactive code text until wrapped in a proper script tag. I can now assign the entire AJAX response to a string, extract the JS script using JQuery's find() and html() and wrap it around a proper script and dump it into the right Section AFTER the sections' markup is populated, so it gets executed at the right time.

QUESTION: Is this a convoluted approach and if so, what is a better, cleaner or more acceptable approach? Remember, it is not the extraction of the script that is complicating things. It is the timely execution of the scripts and the limitations of .html() stripping scripts that drives this convoluted logic.

Comment: Why are you injecting JS blocks instead of calling already loaded functions?

Comment: @Diodeus Because the logic of the JS itself is generated on the server side based upon certain db-based data. That includes the creation of certain elements and applicable styles... all dynamically generated on the server side. Even if I had pre-defined functions, I would still have to call them and a <script> tag will have to be generated. I experimented with the idea of using DATA- tags to pass this data to the client and have pre-defined functions operate on the newly created elements. But that was getting too complicated. In theory you are right though.

Comment: You should consider a JSON-based representation of your UI data and using a templating system to populate the DOM, such as underscore.js or moustache.js. Also, you can achieve what you need using AJAX callbacks, rather than affecting actions with injected script blocks. I used to do EXACTLY what you're doing when I first started using AJAX. No biggie, but there are better ways to do it these days.

Comment: @Diodeus I will take a look at underscore.js and moustache.js. Would not be fair to comment without looking at them first. Do not want to live in an ignorance-is-bliss situation. Thanks.

Comment: There is a little bit of a learning curve, but once you're over that, it just works and you end up writing a lot less code.

Comment: I understand. It took me some time to start using JQuery because I thought I knew JS very well. Now that I use JQuery, I wonder why I did not start using it all along. I had the reverse experience with PhP frameworks. I realized that what I know in PhP and the "framework" I had implemented for myself were good enough to avoid PhP frameworks. Thanks again.

Comment: @Diodeus Did some reading on moustache.js, underscore.js and backbone.js. Certainly helpful and definitely informative. Thanks for pointing in that direction.